# Getting Apache POI to work with Java on Eclipse - how to build

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, apache, ant

I'm quite a newbie to all this stuff, so please do excuse my stupid questions if there are any!

I've been trying to use Java to work on some Excel Files, so I wanted to get the Apache POI. If I understood well it's juste a bunch of libraries that allow the user to edit Excel files with Java on Eclipse.

I've followed the official guide

> https://poi.apache.org/howtobuild.html

I've done almost everything, installed Apache Ant and Apache Forrest as the guide says (I used a couple of other tutorials to get this done) and all that is okay.

However I'm stuck with the next steps "Building targets with Ant" and "Working with Eclipse", especially the second one when the guide says

> "build Apache POI using Ant as described above to get all required 3rd
>   party libraries downloaded"

To put it simply I have absolutely no idea what it means. Could anyone explain to me? I guess that I have to use the last "Ant target" which is "docs", I've searched other tutorials, but didn't find any... I don't even know how to use Ant/Forrest

Thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a bad idea to simply provide a link, but [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/19/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/) really helps.

From the given link, you could download the [sourcecode](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7yo2HclmjI4NDd3Nzd2T1Y4YTA/edit).
It is a complete project, with all the jars in the right place.
You could just replace the existing java files with your own files, or follow the structure to figure out where to put the jars in your own project.

The required jars are:

- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- poi-3.9-20121203.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar
- xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

Hope this is useful to you! :)

> Taken from: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/19/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/

Comment: It not really a bad idea in my case ;) I just need this to work, and actually it's much clearer this way! I felt that what I was doing was too complicated and it was the case, I should've asked first

Comment: Thanks! and to dkatzel too

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build the jars yourself.  You can download precompiled jars from [the POI download page](https://poi.apache.org/download.html), then unzip/tar the binary distribution file and put all the jars in your classpath